# Can't use specific base path for spring actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-starter

I've created a spring boot application and it has ServletRegistrationBean:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> restApi() {
    final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext);
    final ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(dispatcherServlet, "/api/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

and I want to set base path for Actuator as "/api":

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/api
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=/v1/health
```

But this doesn't work. For any else base path it works correctly
**{{localhost}}/api GET returns list of endpoints**, but **{{localhost}}/api/v1/health GET returns 404**

my other rest API which starts with "/api/v1/" work fine
So is there a way how set identical base path for rest API and Actuator endpoints?

Comment: long shot but maybe try putting the /v1/health in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found:

```
endpoints.health.enabled=true
server.servlet.path=/api
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/v1
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=health
```